# DllNotFoundException: gpg

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

a friend and I are developing a game in Unity for Android, and we want to include some leaderboards with the Google Play Games Services, but we can't get the login to work.

We are using for the login the script MainGui from the minimal sample project of the Google Play Games Plugin. When we press the authenticate button it keeps saying "authenticating":

```
if (!Social.localUser.authenticated)
        {
            // Authenticate
            mWaitingForAuth = true;
            mStatusText = "Authenticating...";
            Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
            {
                mWaitingForAuth = false;
                if (success)
                {
                    mStatusText = "Welcome " + Social.localUser.userName;
                }
                else
                {
                    mStatusText = "Authentication failed.";
                }
            });
        }
```

Looking in the logcat, there is an error:

```
E/Unity: DllNotFoundException: gpg
at (wrapper managed-to-native) GooglePlayGames.Native.Cwrapper.Builder:GameServices_Builder_Construct ()
at GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.GameServicesBuilder.Create () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient.InitializeGameServices () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient.Authenticate (System.Action`2 callback, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Authenticate (System.Action`2 callback, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesLocalUser.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at LogInAndroid.OnGUI () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

We have been searching for hours and tried other answers as well as removed and re-added the plugin to the project, checked the api keys, built from a different computer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue is raised and marked closed in the play-games-for-unity-repo by playService : https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/287

> The solution to it that has worked for a few people can be found here. Check the steps mentioned here?
>
> https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/280#issuecomment-64280552

Comment: That solution does not work anymore as the build_plugin.sh does not exist in the current version.